# Adding OpenSeaMap to QGIS QuickMapServices

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices, openseamap

I'd like to add OpenSeaMap to QuickMapServices. Their wiki  http://wiki.openseamap.org/index.php?title=De:OpenSeaMap_in_Website has some usage examples and lists the following tile servers:

```
http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/ 
http://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/
```

But all attempts to configure these servers in QuickMapServices have resulted in layers that look like scrambled noise / confetti.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

URL should be:

```
http://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png    
http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

[image]

Result:

[image]